# sort json array by value jq bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I want to sort below array based on `groupId` such that keys with smaller `groupId` come first in array.

```
[
  {
    "groupId": 11,
    "lowerThreshold": 33,
    "target": {
      "alarm_id": 22
    },
    "thresholdPeriod": 3,
    "upperThreshold": 44
  },
  {
    "groupId": 31,
    "lowerThreshold": 33,
    "target": {
      "alarm_id": 122
    },
    "thresholdPeriod": 3,
    "upperThreshold": 44
  },
  {
    "groupId": "0",
    "target": {
      "alarm_id": "69"
    },
    "upperThreshold": "20",
    "lowerThreshold": "10",
    "thresholdPeriod": "5"
  }
]
```

Expectation is

```
[
  {
    "groupId": "0",
    "target": {
      "alarm_id": "69"
    },
    "upperThreshold": "20",
    "lowerThreshold": "10",
    "thresholdPeriod": "5"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 11,
    "lowerThreshold": 33,
    "target": {
      "alarm_id": 22
    },
    "thresholdPeriod": 3,
    "upperThreshold": 44
  },
  {
    "groupId": 31,
    "lowerThreshold": 33,
    "target": {
      "alarm_id": 122
    },
    "thresholdPeriod": 3,
    "upperThreshold": 44
  }
]
```

Comment: your `groupId`s are non-uniform types, e.g.: `"0"` is type _string_, while others are _numerical_. Would be much easier if you allowed normalization of groupId values to the same type, then sorting would be trivial. Otherwise (if your requirement is to keep them in their original format), it'll complicate the answer a bit

Comment: in the latter case the answer would be `jq 'sort_by(.groupId | tonumber)'`

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry . I got the requierd answer.

Comment: jq's sort is heterogeneous so using `tonumber` may be unnecessary (or even wrong, depending on the actual range of .groupId values). As @Dmitry has said, though, some clarity about the requirements would be helpful (hopefully for everyone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sort_by` like following:

```
jq 'sort_by(.groupId)'
```

Comment: This answer is correct if groupId is number. Other wise *jq 'sort_by(.groupId | tonumber)' *can be used.

Comment: @arun_kushwaha - neither `sort` nor `sort_by` requires homogeneity.