# Produce output from JSON for values and sort them by number

Tags: json, jq

I have a jq query to get two values from the JSON file:
`jq -r '.[] | [.name, .size] | join(",")' file.json`
This gives me an output like:

```
name1,1024
name2,300
name3,512
```

What I want is to sort them by number. I've tried to pipe the query by `| sort_by(.size | tonumber)` but it always fail on `Cannot iterate over string ("name1,1024")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sort json array by value jq bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60280053/sort-json-array-by-value-jq-bash)

Comment: it should have been `jq -r 'sort_by(.size) | join(",")'`

Comment: No, none of those work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq -r '[.[] | {name, size}] | sort_by(.size) | [.[][]] | join(",")'
```